# How to restore apache configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I have placed .htaccess file in my server's root folder with following content,

```
Redirect 303 /index.html http://mysite.com/index.php
```

to redirect my index.html to index.php,

but it has created one issue that some the my `.php` files are not getting displayed, it displays blank page.

so want to restore all the changes done by `.htaccess` file,

do anyone have any idea how to get out of this problem or how to restore all the changes done by `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess file does not change any configuration in your server. If you don't want it, you can just remove the file, rename it, or move it out of your server path.

Comment: thanks khaled, your statement "htaccess file does not change any configuration in your server" gave me huge relief, but .php files are stopped getting displayed after i have put this .htaccess file. i have removed .htaccess file, but still issue exists

Comment: @ManojNakum: so, you need to double-check your configurations.

Comment: i am new to all this, can you please explain it in detail, how to do that?

Comment: You need to start by looking at apache error log. Also, you can try to revert the recent changes if you can remember them!